# Proxy server using Indy

Tags: delphi, networking, proxy, delphi-2010, indy

I'm new to Indy and I want to build a simple proxy-server with it. This is a quite big library, and I just don't know where to start. When client connects to server, OnExucute fires up and receives client connection as parameter (AContext.Connection).

I want to do following:

```
[client connection] := AContext.Connection
read host/port from [client connection]
[remote connection] := connect to host/port
while both connections alive:
  if data available in [client connection]:
    read data from [client connection]
    write data to [remote connection]
  if data available in [remote connection]:
    read data from [remote connection]
    write data to [client connection]
```

The question is what functions should I use for that? There is `IOHandler` property in Connection object with tons of them. Please, help.

I'm using Indy that ships with Delphi2010.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Indy has its own proxy components that do what you are asking for.  Look at the `TIdMappedPortTCP` and `TIdHTTPProxyServer` components as starting places.

`TIdMappedPortTCP` is a general-purpose proxy that just passes raw data back and forth.  You can use its `OnConnect` event to dynamically configure the target Host/Port for that connection (such as by reading it from the client), or you can set its `MappedHost` and `MappedPort` properties statically for all connections.  You can use its `OnExecute` and `OnOutboundData` events to modify data as it passes through the proxy, if needed.

`TIdHTTPProxyServer` is a specialized proxy only for HTTP-based proxying, where the client uses the HTTP `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, and `CONNECT` verbs, specifying absolute URLs to the target Host/Port, and then passes HTTP headers and data back and forth as needed (`CONNECT` is commonly used for proxying an SSL/TLS connection through a firewall).

Comment: Really wise advice, thanks! Both components' sources are very useful. If someone is interested, finally I came with something like that: http://pastebin.com/ixt2gssD