# How to make a simple proxy server?

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy10

I wanted to create a simple proxy to my localhost(xampp). I've looked into IdHTTPProxyServer but there is no available example of how to use it.

my intention is to monitor the Post/Get request of my application at runtime just like a debugger.

my application will Post/Get through localhost:8080 and then my proxy will be served as a bridge to localhost:80

any suggestion or example?

I am using D2009, D2010 must support Unicode.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Must you make your own? There are dozens, if not hundreds, to choose from. (If this is a learning exercise, knock yourself out! I just wonder if this is a tool or a project...)

Comment: some-kind of a tool for my projects. my project has a lot of xmls, images and audio streams. was that so hard?

Comment: I'm mostly curious if using a proxy such as Squid or Polipo or Tinyproxy might be able to meet your needs; Polipo at least stores its data in easy to read format off disks, if you need it.

Comment: I've used this: http://www.3proxy.ru/

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136226/proxy-server-using-indy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not Indy, but Synapse (I use it with Lazarus) has a Proxy Server Example included which should work on Delphi too. It worked well for me on FPC. The Demo is included in the Sources you get here:

http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/download

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Overbyte ICS TCP/IP library](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html), on the "user made" page you have a lot of proxy samples, one is [tgphttpproxy](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/tgphttpproxy.htm).